# Loop creating DataFrames to makeup larger DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looping through sheets in an excel file, doing a calculation, and then creating a DataFrame (only 1 column, 15 rows) from each. Each time I loop through a sheet from the excel file and create it's DataFrame, I would like to add that to a larger DataFrame.

```
sheet = 0 
peptides = []
for i in range (5):
    f = one_sheet(file,sheet,index)
    sheet = sheet + 1 
    peptides.append(f)
```

so i've created a list of the dataframes, and I tried:

```
    df_final = pd.concat([peptides], axis=1)
```

but I get an error- TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object

i've also tried something like:

```
sheet = 0 
peptides = []
df_final = pd.DataFrame(index=index)
for i in range (5):
    f = one_sheet(file,sheet,index)
    sheet = sheet + 1 
    peptides.append(f)
    df_final.add(f, axis=1)
```

which only returns

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [500, 250, 125, 63, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0.5, .25, .125, .0625, .03125]

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `one_sheet`?

Comment: have you tried df_final = pd.concat(peptides, axis=1)? That is peptides without [ ].

Comment: Pandas has a very nice documentation on how to concatenate DataFrames:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: @salehinejad that's all it was! haha, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I see you have tried to answer the question and once someone else has done that, you have marked the question as duplicate. This is not encouraging.

Comment: @salehinejad I haven't tried answering this question. What are you talking about?